# multi structure output to list

Tags: matlab, structure

Below is some code that will work in extracting out the a cell array of ID names from the structure. It uses a for loop to achieve this. However I am wondering if there is a way to perform the same task without using a forloop?

```
tft(1).Id = 'Name1';
tft(1).Desc = 'goes by the name';
tft(2).Id = 'Name2';
tft(2).Desc = 'hates the name';

for a=1:length(tft)
    list{a} = tft(a).Id
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a documentation page dedicated to this question: [Access Elements of a Nonscalar Struct Array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-multiple-elements-of-a-nonscalar-struct-array.html).

Since doing `tft.Id` returns a comma separated list, you can convert it into a cell array directly by enclosing it in curly braces:

```
list = {tft.Id};
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now I know what this is called.